# How to get to Facebook User Page by a known app scoped User ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Till today there have been methods to get to Facebook User Page by user id. I mean ID, that facebook API returns to our app: https://graph.facebook.com/10152384781676191?fields=link

```
{
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10152384781676191/",
  "id": "10152384781676191"
}
```

But none of the methods works any more:

- https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10152384781676191 - does not work
- https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=10152384781676191 - does not work
- https://facebook.com/10152384781676191 - does not work

---

**UPDATE:** It seems the following happened: [according to TechCrunch, malicious sites pulled data form public user profiles.](https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/18/login-with-facebook-data-hijacked-by-javascript-trackers/)

After TechCrunch article Facebook immediately blocked the URLs that Graph API returns: `graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{user-id}/?fields=link&access_token={access-token}` . They "*...are working on instituting additional authentication and rate limiting...*".

---

Any 1) quick workarounds and/or 2) permanent solution?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2054375031451090/

Comment: Well if you find a solution, please add it here. That facebook thread is riddled with morons talking about the profile picture and access tokens. Which as no bearing on the original bug posted. I dont have the patience to follow a spammed thread like that.

Comment: There is no solution so far.
 Meanwhile a similar, but other, issue appeared the same day with picture API.
 Facebook admin closed all picture bug reports as duplicate to the user profile link bug. That was the reason why the facebook thread was spammed with the picture subject.
 While adding &access_token= parameter resolves the picture issue it does not help to the original bug posted.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/19/facebook-login-changes-address-abuse/

Comment: Related: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/185630995395938/

Comment: Facebook now only provide a Scoped-User link after permission and this link only opens if you are a friend of the user or the user himself. What i was wondering is that, cant someone ask the user to click on a button that will visit that url and thus pull the actual profile and save it to that user? i wish i know how to do that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook banned the **link** property in their Graph API intentionally. Now they propose to fill out a from in order to review each case individually.

The form: https://go.fb.com/2018-FB4D-platform-review-form.html

News update from April 20th: [Facebook Login Changes to Address Abuse](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/19/facebook-login-changes-address-abuse/)

> It came to our attention yesterday that some third-party tracking scripts on websites were directly accessing Facebook public profiles. While investigating this issue, we have taken immediate action by:
>
> - Disabling the ability to resolve the app-scoped user ID (ASID) returned by Facebook Login to a Facebook profile page, even for logged-in users.
> - Instituting rate limiting of profile picture requests, to further prevent any third parties from trying to link people's activity across different websites using the application-specific identifiers issued by Facebook Login.
>
> We don’t take breaking changes lightly, but we believe that these updates will help protect people’s privacy and increase trust across the ecosystem. If you have an urgent issue in need of resolution, please fill out this form and someone from our team will get in touch with you.
>
> Thank you for your patience while we work to resolve this issue as soon as possible.